# The faster of two SQL queries, sort and select top 1, or select MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server

Which one is faster of the following two queries?

## 1

```
SELECT TOP 1 order_date
FROM         orders WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE customer_id = 9999999
ORDER BY order_date DESC
```

## 2

```
SELECT MAX(order_date)
FROM         orders WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE customer_id = 9999999
```

Comment: run the two queries and measure!

Comment: Then I wouldn't have a question to ask on SO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With an index on `order_date`, they are of same performance.

Without an index, `MAX` is a little bit faster, since it will use `Stream Aggregation` rather than `Top N Sort`.

Answer (score 2):

ORDER BY is almost always slowest.  The table's data must be sorted.

Aggregate functions shouldn't slow things down as much as a sort.

However, some aggregate functions use a sort as part of their implementation.  So a particular set of tables in a particular database product must be tested experimentally to see which is faster -- for that set of data.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the first, because the second requires it to go through an aggregate function.

However, as marc_s said, test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't answer that without knowing at least something about your indexes (have you got one on customer_id, on order_date?), the amount of data in the table, the state of your statistics etc.etc.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how big your table is. On the second query, i guess there's no need for "TOP 1," since MAX only returns one value. If I were you, I would use the second query.

Comment: That was a copy/paste mistake. Thanks for the catch.